# How to get entities with direction in relation extraction?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, data-science

I have been working with relation extraction for a week. But what I need is direction between two entities, such as Company_x got bought by Company_y. So the model should predict the entities like Company_y->bought-> Company_X. Any models you guys think will be helpful for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The passive voice is usually a good indicator of the direction of the relationship.

You can extract, from the context between the two entities, a pattern which starts by a verb, and then detecting the presence or absence of the passive voice.

Some simple proof-of-concept code (this could actually be much more simpler using RegexpParser from NLTK)

```
from nltk import pos_tag
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer

lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
aux_verbs = ['be']

def detect_passive_voice(pattern):
    passive_voice = False

    if len(pattern) >= 3:
        if pattern[0][1].startswith('V'):
            verb = lmtzr.lemmatize(pattern[0][0], 'v')
            if verb in aux_verbs:
                if (pattern[1][1] == 'VBN' or pattern[1][1] == 'VBD') and pattern[-1][0] == 'by':
                    passive_voice = True

            # past verb + by
            elif (pattern[-2][1] == 'VBN' or pattern[-2][1] == 'VBD') and pattern[-1][0] == 'by':
                passive_voice = True

        # past verb + by
        elif (pattern[-2][1] == 'VBN' or pattern[-2][1] == 'VBD') and pattern[-1][0] == 'by':
                passive_voice = True

    # past verb + by
    elif len(pattern) >= 2:
        if (pattern[-2][1] == 'VBN' or pattern[-2][1] == 'VBD') and pattern[-1][0] == 'by':
            passive_voice = True

return passive_voice
```

Running some examples:

```
In [4]: tokens = word_tokenize("was bought by")
   ...: tags = pos_tag(tokens)
   ...: detect_passive_voice(tags)
Out[4]: True

In [5]: tokens = word_tokenize("mailed the letter")
   ...: tags = pos_tag(tokens)
   ...: detect_passive_voice(tags)
Out[5]: False

In [7]: tokens = word_tokenize("was mailed by")
   ...: tags = pos_tag(tokens)
   ...: detect_passive_voice(tags)
Out[7]: True
```

You can add more auxiliary verbs and also allow for the existence of adverbs or adjectives in-between.

Comment: thanks for your help. It's really a good idea to have an active and passive voice in determining the direction of relation.

Comment: thanks, that code is a bit messy, I will try to find time to re-write that with NLTK's RegexpParser: 
https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/chunk/regexp.html#RegexpParser